# Price formula for a claim with payoff $\bf{1}_{W_T \geq K}$

Tags: risk-neutral-measure

Let $dW^{\mathbb{P}}(t)$ be a standard BM under $\mathbb{P}$ and $dW^{\mathbb{Q}}(t)$ a standard BM under $\mathbb{Q}$. We know that

$$dW^{\mathbb{P}}(t)=dW^{\mathbb{Q}}(t) - adt$$

where $a$ is a constant. Can someone explain to me how you derive the price formula for a claim with payoff $\bf{1}_{W_T \geq K}$. Using the risk-neutral valuation formula. Any help or tips would be appreciated.